# Code on JSFiddle not working in browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have this code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ftk5c8z/402/

when i try it to the browser it does not work.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<select class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" id="ListResort" multiple name="ListResort" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Select Resort</option>
<optgroup label="Hotels &amp; Resorts">
<option value="Miramar by Pestana São Tomé">Miramar by Pestana São Tomé</option>
<option value="Pestana Alvor Atlantico">Pestana Alvor Atlantico</option>
<option value="Pestana Alvor Park">Pestana Alvor Park</option>
<option value="Pestana Alvor Park 2">Pestana Alvor Park 2</option>
<option value="Pestana Alvor Praia">Pestana Alvor Praia</option>
<option value="Pestana Alvor South Beach">Pestana Alvor South Beach</option>
<option value="Pestana Buenos Aires">Pestana Buenos Aires</option>
<option value="Pestana Caracas">Pestana Caracas</option>
<option value="Pestana Carlton Madeira">Pestana Carlton Madeira</option>
<option value="Pestana Casablanca">Pestana Casablanca</option>
<option value="Pestana Cascais">Pestana Cascais</option>
<option value="Pestana Casino Park">Pestana Casino Park</option>
<option value="Pestana Cayo Coco">Pestana Cayo Coco</option>
<option value="Pestana Chelsea Bridge Hotel">Pestana Chelsea Bridge Hotel</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('#ListResort').select2();
$('#ListResort').select2().select2('val', ["Miramar by Pestana São Tomé", "Pestana Alvor Park 2"]).trigger("change");

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its working for me.

Comment: @priya_singh the question poster tolds the same. it is working fine in fiddle but when try in browser it doesn't work.

Comment: @SudharsanS I tried in Chrome and its working fine.

Comment: What does "try in browser" mean?  Did you save an html file locally and open with `file:\\` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, i tried to save an html file locally. it shows an error on console saying `Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined(…)` and only a value is showed

Comment: i either have this in mvc on a view and the error is the same... only shows one value of the two passed in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your includes / external resources.

On the fiddle, you include both 3.5.0 and 4.0.3, but in the question you only include 4.0.3.

If you change the local version to 3.5.0, it works fine:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

**More Info**

The `.select2("val" ..` was removed in 4.0.0, replaced by `.val(...`

https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-methods